# PyCharm: `null` extra fields not permitted when instatiating a pydantic base model using kwargs

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pydantic

I have this class:

```py
class OptimizerConfig(pydantic.BaseModel):
   
    learning_rate: StrictFloat
    learning_rate_decay: Optional[StrictFloat]

    class Config:

        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        extra = Extra.forbid
```

and the following code to create an instance of it:

```py
params = {"learning_rate": 0.1, "learning_rate_decay": 0.1}
optimizer_config = OptimizerConfig(**params)
```

Everything works as expected: the class raises `pydantic.error.wrappers.ValidationError` if an extra argument is passed or if the arguments do not follow the specified type i.e. `learning_rate=1`.

However, I get the following in PyCharm every time I use this approach:

> `null` extra fields not permitted

The problem does not appear if I do this instead:

```py
OptimizerConfig(learning_rate=0.1, learning_rate_decay=0.1)
```

I made some research but I can't seem to find the reason for it. The code works as expected nonetheless and I don't get any exception. Anyone has got the same behaviour by any chance?

Comment: Where do you see the "null extra fields not permitted" message? What are the versions of  PyCharm, Python and Pydantic?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I see it when I hover over the red highlight in the IDE. I am using PyCharm CE 2022.1, Python version is 3.8.13 and Pydantic version is 1.9.0.

Comment: I see the same sort of error message if I pass one more extra parameter during object instantiation e.g. `extra_param=42`. In this case, PyCharm will say `extra_param extra field not permitted`. For some reason I can't understand, PyCharm thinks there is a field in the dictionary called `null` - it sounds very weird.

Comment: I don't see such red highlight or message in PyCharm CE 2022.1.3 with Sonarlint plugin 6.8.0.50884, Python 3.9.7 and Pydantic 1.9.0 on Windows when I paste your code in a Python file. Maybe try disabling PyCharm plugins and see it the message disappears or update/reinstall PyCharm.